# How to choose a value from two columns (First and Second) to subtract from another column (Third), based on condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjsz3.png)

There are 4 columns in total.

****VALUE_DIFF is the calculated value****. This is based on if column "SECOND" has a value greater than 0, then subtract column value from "SECOND" and "BASE_COLUMN" [ SECOND - BASE_COLUMN]. If column "SECOND" is 0 then subtract column value from "FRIST" and "BASE COLUMN" [FIRST - BASED_COLUMN]

Wondering how can **Pandas** execute with this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['DIFF'] = np.where(df['SECOND'].gt(0), df['SECOND'], df['FIRST']) - df['BASE_COLUMN']
```

What is same like:

```
df['DIFF'] = np.where(df['SECOND'].gt(0), 
                      df['SECOND']- df['BASE_COLUMN'], 
                      df['FIRST']- df['BASE_COLUMN'])
```